# Python multiprocessing apply_async never returns result on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I am trying to follow a very simple multiprocessing example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def cube(x):
    return x**3

pool    = mp.Pool(processes=2)
results = [pool.apply_async(cube, args=x) for x in range(1,7)]
```

However, on my windows machine, I am not able to get the result (on ubuntu 12.04LTS it runs perfectly).

If I inspect `results`, I see the following:

```
[<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x01FF0910>,
 <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x01FF0950>,
 <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x01FF0990>,
 <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x01FF09D0>,
 <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x01FF0A10>,
 <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x01FF0A50>]
```

If I run `results[0].ready()` I always get `False`.

If I run `results[0].get()` the python interpreter freezes, waiting to get the result that never comes.

The example is as simple as it gets, so I am thinking this is a low level bug relating to the OS (I am on Windows 7). But perhaps someone else has a better idea?

Comment: `multiprocessing` doesn't work so well in an interactive Python interpreter. Does it work when you run this code as a script?

Comment: @moarningsun it didn't work in a script as well. dano's solution did the trick

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes here. First, you must declare the `Pool` inside an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard [when running on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#windows). Second, you have to pass the `args` keyword argument a sequence, even if you're only passing one argument. So putting that together:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def cube(x):
    return x**3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool    = mp.Pool(processes=2)
    results = [pool.apply_async(cube, args=(x,)) for x in range(1,7)]
    print([result.get() for result in results])
```

Output:

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
```

**Edit:**

Oh, as moarningsun mentions, `multiprocessing` [does not work well](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction) in the interactive interpreter:

> **Note**
>
> Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be
>   importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines
>   however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples,
>   such as the `multiprocessing.Pool` examples will not work in the
>   interactive interpreter.

So you'll need to actually execute the code as a script to test it properly.

Answer (score 8):

I was running python 3 and the IDE was spyder in anaconda (windows ) and so this trick doesn't work for me. I tried a lot but couldn't make any difference. I got the reason for my problem and is the same listed by dano in his note. But after a long day of searching I got some solution and it helped me to run the same code my windows machine. This website helped me to get the solution:

http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Multiprocessing-Pool-woes-td5047050.html

Since I  was using the python 3, I changed the program a little like this:

```
from types import FunctionType
import marshal

def _applicable(*args, **kwargs):
  name = kwargs['__pw_name']
  code = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_code'])
  gbls = globals() #gbls = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_gbls'])
  defs = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_defs'])
  clsr = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_clsr'])
  fdct = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_fdct'])
  func = FunctionType(code, gbls, name, defs, clsr)
  func.fdct = fdct
  del kwargs['__pw_name']
  del kwargs['__pw_code']
  del kwargs['__pw_defs']
  del kwargs['__pw_clsr']
  del kwargs['__pw_fdct']
  return func(*args, **kwargs)

def make_applicable(f, *args, **kwargs):
  if not isinstance(f, FunctionType): raise ValueError('argument must be a function')
  kwargs['__pw_name'] = f.__name__  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_code'] = marshal.dumps(f.__code__)   # edited
  kwargs['__pw_defs'] = marshal.dumps(f.__defaults__)  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_clsr'] = marshal.dumps(f.__closure__)  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_fdct'] = marshal.dumps(f.__dict__)   # edited
  return _applicable, args, kwargs

def _mappable(x):
  x,name,code,defs,clsr,fdct = x
  code = marshal.loads(code)
  gbls = globals() #gbls = marshal.loads(gbls)
  defs = marshal.loads(defs)
  clsr = marshal.loads(clsr)
  fdct = marshal.loads(fdct)
  func = FunctionType(code, gbls, name, defs, clsr)
  func.fdct = fdct
  return func(x)

def make_mappable(f, iterable):
  if not isinstance(f, FunctionType): raise ValueError('argument must be a function')
  name = f.__name__    # edited
  code = marshal.dumps(f.__code__)   # edited
  defs = marshal.dumps(f.__defaults__)  # edited
  clsr = marshal.dumps(f.__closure__)  # edited
  fdct = marshal.dumps(f.__dict__)  # edited
  return _mappable, ((i,name,code,defs,clsr,fdct) for i in iterable)
```

After this function , the above problem code is also changed a little like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from poolable import make_applicable, make_mappable

def cube(x):
  return x**3

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pool    = Pool(processes=2)
  results = [pool.apply_async(*make_applicable(cube,x)) for x in range(1,7)]
  print([result.get(timeout=10) for result in results])
```

And I got the output as :

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
```

I am thinking that this post may be useful for some of the windows users.