# python multiprocessing returning error 'module' object has no attribute 'myfunc'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-2.x

First off, I am very new to multiprocessing, and I can't seem to make a very simple and straightforward example work. This is the example I working with:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

everytime I run a code I am getting this error multiple times :

```
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\traitlets.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
  warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 1132, in find_class
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'worker'
```

I know that this question is very vague but I if anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

I am on Windows, I run it in Anaconda with python 2.7, the code is exactly the same as above, nothing more nothing less! I run it directly in the console in the IDE

EDIT: It looks like when I run the code directly in command prompt it works just fine, but doing it the console using Anaconda won't work. anybody knows why?

Comment: your example works fine here. Are you sure you did not "simplify" the code?

Comment: How did you run the program? Is this on Windows?

Comment: I am on windows, I run it in Anaconda with python 2.7, code is exactly the same as above, nothing more nothing less! I run it directly in the console in the IDE

Comment: It works fine for me on linux and python3 (after fixing 2-to-3 issues) doing `ipython3 test.py`. Windows is different because it must pickle more of the execution environment to run the child. I think the windows implementation can't find your module to finish the unpickling. How you run it may help determine why.

Comment: @tdelaney like when I run the code directly in cmd it works just fine, but doing it the console using anaconda won't work. anybody knows why?

Answer (score -1):

Anaconda doesn't like multiprocessing as explained [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489352/multiprocessing-program-has-attributeerror-in-anaconda-notebook)
 answer.

From the answer:

> This is because of the fact that multiprocessing does not work well in the interactive interpreter. The main reason is that there is no fork() function applicable in windows. It is explained on their web page itself.

Thank you!