# Multiprocessing with pandas data frames hangs at queue.get() and pool.map()

Tags: pandas, macos, python-multiprocessing, python-3.8

I am new to multiprocessing. I am using **`pandas`** and **`python3.8`** in **`MacOS`** with `8 cores` for data analysis. Without multiprocessing my current program takes *`71 seconds`* for a `60000x60000` data frame, I wish to speed it up more and use it for a larger data frame.

I followed some online guides to write a simple function to print a number. But it hangs when the pool is executed.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
q = mp.Queue()

def func(x): 
  print(x[i])

def main():
  start = time.time()
  pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count()-1))
  x=np.arange(0,100,1)
  odor_presence = pool.map(func ,x)
  pool.join()
  print('Execution time: ', time.time()-start)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging around for a while I realized it is because of my anaconda environment it will not let me use any multiprocessing. The code works perfectly in a system without anaconda.

I found this as well which describes the issue and problem.
[Multiprocessing program has AttributeError in Anaconda notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489352/multiprocessing-program-has-attributeerror-in-anaconda-notebook)