# Passing a class to multiprocessing pool in python on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

In order to use `multiprocessing` in interactive python on windows (miniconda), I've found a very useful code that works very well. The code, however, can not pass the `self` argument inside a class to the function to be pooled. Here is my code that works on google colab but never finishes on windows iPython:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from poolable import make_applicable, make_mappable

def worker(d):
    """worker function"""
    for i in range(10000):
      j = i **(1/3) + d.bias
    return j

class dummy():
  def __init__(self):
    self.bias = 1000
  def calc(self):
    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    results = {}
    for i in range(5):
        results[i] = (pool.apply_async(*make_applicable(worker,self)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print([results[i].get() for i in range(5)])

d=dummy()
d.calc()
```

The code works well on windows if I pass other types of variables, for example:

```
results[i] = (pool.apply_async(*make_applicable(worker,self.bias)))
```

But when I pass `self` to the function the process never finishes. I have no idea what to do.

`poolable.py` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37140995/7490554):

```
from types import FunctionType
import marshal

def _applicable(*args, **kwargs):
  name = kwargs['__pw_name']
  code = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_code'])
  gbls = globals() #gbls = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_gbls'])
  defs = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_defs'])
  clsr = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_clsr'])
  fdct = marshal.loads(kwargs['__pw_fdct'])
  func = FunctionType(code, gbls, name, defs, clsr)
  func.fdct = fdct
  del kwargs['__pw_name']
  del kwargs['__pw_code']
  del kwargs['__pw_defs']
  del kwargs['__pw_clsr']
  del kwargs['__pw_fdct']
  return func(*args, **kwargs)

def make_applicable(f, *args, **kwargs):
  if not isinstance(f, FunctionType): raise ValueError('argument must be a function')
  kwargs['__pw_name'] = f.__name__  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_code'] = marshal.dumps(f.__code__)   # edited
  kwargs['__pw_defs'] = marshal.dumps(f.__defaults__)  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_clsr'] = marshal.dumps(f.__closure__)  # edited
  kwargs['__pw_fdct'] = marshal.dumps(f.__dict__)   # edited
  return _applicable, args, kwargs

def _mappable(x):
  x,name,code,defs,clsr,fdct = x
  code = marshal.loads(code)
  gbls = globals() #gbls = marshal.loads(gbls)
  defs = marshal.loads(defs)
  clsr = marshal.loads(clsr)
  fdct = marshal.loads(fdct)
  func = FunctionType(code, gbls, name, defs, clsr)
  func.fdct = fdct
  return func(x)

def make_mappable(f, iterable):
  if not isinstance(f, FunctionType): raise ValueError('argument must be a function')
  name = f.__name__    # edited
  code = marshal.dumps(f.__code__)   # edited
  defs = marshal.dumps(f.__defaults__)  # edited
  clsr = marshal.dumps(f.__closure__)  # edited
  fdct = marshal.dumps(f.__dict__)  # edited
  return _mappable, ((i,name,code,defs,clsr,fdct) for i in iterable)
```

**Edit:**

It seems that the problem exist not only for `self` but also for any other classes that pass to the `make_applicable` function. The following code also don't finish:

```
class dummy2():
  def __init__(self):
    self.bias = 1000  

class dummy():
  def __init__(self):
    self.bias = 1000
  def copy(self):
    return copy.deepcopy(self)
  def calc(self):
    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    results = {}
    for i in range(5):
      d = dummy2()
      results[i] = pool.apply_async(*make_applicable(worker,d))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print([results[i].get() for i in range(5)])
```

Comment: One problem: Active code (last two lines in main script) must be guarded with: `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for your comment. But the mentioned problem is still unresolved with this modification.

Comment: SMA.D as I said in my post, you cannot pass 'self' like this in process! self is an instance of a python class, you need a way to marshall it and demarshar ll! self is an object which it is created in the main process so when you create another process, self cannot be passed as process never share the same memory...I don't know if you understand what I mean :)

Comment: How are you executing your code. You haven't shown how you actually run your *program*.

Comment: SMA.D customize "_applicable" and "make_applicable" to take in account serialization and désérialization of instance of "dummy"...you can use Pickle for example

Comment: @wwii I simply copy the code in jupyter notebook or google colab and then press shift+Enter! :)

Comment: Is your question `Why does it work in colab and not in jupyter notebook?` or is youir question `How can I make this work in jupyter notebook?`?

Comment: @wwii The second one. I really whant to make it work in jupyter notebook on windows, I have a time consuming task that I want to make it faster using multiple CPU cores.

Comment: SMA.D can you test the code in my update please?

Comment: @user1438644 I don't understand why, but it seems that `make_applicable` function can't also handle classes as input (on windows).

Comment: @user1438644 I can run the same code using console, as explained by wwii, so I think the problem should be related to jupyter rather than passing instance of an object. Actually, I don't want to share the instance, I want to use the arguments of an instance in the worker function.

Answer (score 1):

Using IPython console:
Put your code in a module (`mp.py`) ensuring the the class instantiation and method call are executed in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` conditional

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from poolable import make_applicable, make_mappable

def worker(d):
    """worker function"""
    for i in range(10000):
      j = i **(1/3) + d.bias
    return j

class Dummy():
  def __init__(self):
#    self.bias = 1000
      self.bias = 10
  def calc(self):
    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    results = {}
    for i in range(5):
        results[i] = (pool.apply_async(*make_applicable(worker,self)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return [results[i].get() for i in range(5)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d=Dummy()
    print(d.calc())
```

Then in the console run the module:

```
In [1]: runfile('P:/pyProjects3/mp.py', wdir='P:/pyProjects3')
[31.543628731482663, 31.543628731482663, 31.543628731482663, 31.543628731482663, 31.543628731482663]
```

---

I have Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda) but don't know how to use it, if I figure it out I'll update this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This method works on windows, therefore the problem should be related to Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code to test

```
import pickle

def worker(d):
    """worker function"""
    d = pickle.loads(d)
    for i in range(10000):
        j = i **(1/3) + d.bias
    return j


class dummy():
    def __init__(self):
    self.bias = 1000
  def calc(self):
      pool = Pool(processes=12)
      results = {}
      for i in range(5):
          x = pickle.dumps(self)
          results[i] = (pool.apply_async(*make_applicable(worker,x)))
      pool.close()
      pool.join()
      print([results[i].get() for i in range(5)])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the same code runs on Google colab!

Comment: so you objective is not to shra the same variable between processes inthat case your code will work

Comment: I have imported pickle, but it doesn't get recognized inside worker: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/content/poolable.py", line 20, in _applicable
    del kwargs['__pw_fdct']
  File "<ipython-input-14-bb026f044c0e>", line 9, in worker
    d = pickle.loads(d)
NameError: name 'pickle' is not defined

Comment: If I import pickle (also) inside worker function, it works on colab. But in jupyter it gives another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\d\miniconda3\envs\netplan\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "D:\Projects\Placement\poolable.py", line 20, in _applicable
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-13-adde7c82a5b1>", line 11, in worker
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'dummy' on <module '_main _' (built-in)>